# Depth first search, use of global variables, and correctness of time

Tags: python, python-2.x, depth-first-search

As I was coding this algorithm I found that some variables that are meant to be global behave as they are intended to behave, but others do not.  Specifically, my boolean arrays, e.g. `processed` and `discovered`, can be modified within any method without the need to declare them.

On the other hand, I had trouble with the variable `time`.  Python complained about incrementing a variable without it being declared.  The solution to this was to specifically declare `time` as a `Global`, and the complaints went away.

Can someone, in a clear way that makes sense, explain the why `time` needs to be declared `Global` and the other global variables do not?  What is the difference between `time` and the other variables?

One other thing.  Can someone check the correctness of the way I'm keeping track of time of entry and time of exit?  According to The Algorithm Design Manual by Skiena, half the difference between time of entry and time of exit for a vertex equals the number of descendants.  But I don't think that's what I'm seeing.

```
# Global variables
MAXV = 7
processed = [None]*MAXV # boolean list of which vertices have been processed
discovered = [None]*MAXV # boolean list of which vertices have been found
parent = [None]*MAXV # integer list of discovery relation
finished = False
entry_time = [None]*MAXV
exit_time = [None]*MAXV
time = 0

class Edgenode:
    def __init__(self, y = None, weight = None, next = None):
        """
        @param y: adjacency info
        @param weight: edge weight, if any
        @param next: next edge in list
        """
        self.y = y
        self.weight = weight
        self.next = next

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges = [], degree = [], nvertices = None, \
                nedges = None, directed = None):
        """
        @param edges: adjency info
        @param degree: outdegree of each vertex
        @param nvertices: number of vertices in graph
        @param nedges: number of edges in graph
        @param directed: is the graph directed? (boolean)
        """
        self.edges = edges # this might be a dictionary, with key being vertex and values being edges
        self.degree = degree
        self.nvertices = nvertices
        self.nedges = nedges
        self.directed = directed

def initialize_graph(graph, directed):
    """
    @param graph: Graph object
    @param directed: boolean
    """
    graph.nvertices = 0
    graph.nedges = 0
    graph.directed = directed

    for i in xrange(MAXV):
        graph.degree.append(0)
        graph.edges.append(None)

def read_graph(graph, directed):
    """
    @param graph: Graph object
    @param directed: boolean
    """
    initialize_graph(graph, directed)
    data = graph_data()

    graph.nvertices = data[0][0] # number of vertices
    m = data[0][1] # number of edges

    for i in xrange(1,m+1):
        x = data[i][0] # vertex x
        y = data[i][1] # vertex y
        insert_edge(graph,x,y,directed)

def insert_edge(graph, x, y, directed):
    """
    @param graph: Graph object
    @param x, y: vertices in edge (x,y)
    @param directed: boolean
    """
    p = Edgenode()
    p.y = y
    p.next = graph.edges[x] #p.next point to whatever is in edges[x] 

    graph.edges[x] = p #edges[x], gets replaced by the new p, which points to whatever was in edges[x] before

    graph.degree[x] += 1

    if (directed == False):
        insert_edge(graph, y, x, True)
    else:
        graph.nedges += 1

def graph_data():
    data = [
            (6,7),
            (1,2),
            (1,6),
            (1,5),
            (2,3),
            (2,5),
            (5,4),
            (3,4)]
    return data

def initialize_search(graph):
    finished = False
    for i in xrange(1,graph.nvertices+1):
        processed[i] = discovered[i] = False
        parent[i] = -1 # the parent of vertex i is parent[i]
        entry_time[i] = exit_time[i] = None

def dfs(graph,v):
    global time
    if finished: #allow for search termination
        return
    discovered[v] = True
    time = time + 1
    entry_time[v] = time

    process_vertex_early(v)

    p = graph.edges[v]
    while p != None:
        y = p.y
        if discovered[y] == False:
            parent[y] = v
            process_edge(v,y)
            dfs(graph,y)
        elif not processed[y] or graph.directed:
            process_edge(v,y)
        if finished:
            return
        p = p.next

    process_vertex_late(v)

    time = time + 1
    exit_time[v] = time

    processed[v] = True

def process_vertex_early(v):
    print "Discovered vertex %d\n"%v

def process_edge(x,y):
    print "Processed edge (%d,%d)\n"%(x,y)

def process_vertex_late(v):
    print "Processed vertex %d\n"%v

def main():
    graph = Graph()
    read_graph(graph, False)
    start = 1
    initialize_search(graph)
    dfs(graph,start)

    for i in xrange(1,graph.nvertices+1):
        print "Entry time for vertix %d: %d"%(i,entry_time[i])
        print "Exit time for vertix %d: %d\n"%(i,exit_time[i])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Some minor points to consider

time is a stdlib module - that makes it a bad candidate for a global variable name! But as the code is written each new call to dfs() needs it.  Why don't you pass the time down to each call and pass it back up as each recursion finishes?

Comment: I implemented it that way too, and it works, but I liked keeping time as global since it's consistent with the style of the algorithm.  Plus, the Java implementation that I translated to Python treats time as global variable.  I figure it's for a good reason.

Comment: Note that `initialize_search` assigns a local variable `finished` while `dfs` accesses a global variable of the same name.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone, in a clear way that makes sense, explain the why time needs to be declared Global and the other global variables do not? What is the difference between time and the other variables?

The `time` variable is an integer and the boolean arrays are lists. In python lists can be modified in place but integers cannot; you need to assign a new value to `time` variable to modify it. The global declaration is only needed for the assignment to the global variable to work.

You would also need to declare the boolean arrays as global in any function or method that would need to assign a new value to them; modifying the existing lists in place as you are now doing does not require the global declaration.

Now, on a bit deeper level, this is about Python using a thing called references when declaring variables. Each variable is a reference to the actual "value". Changing the reference is done with the assignment operator (=). You can freely assign a new reference to any variable that you have declared locally (i.e. inside a function). But when a variable is declared in the global scope, changing the global reference inside another scope requires the global declaration in that scope. The reason for this is to prevent accidental modification of a global variable when the intention was to declare a new local variable with the same name; you have to be explicit when you want to assign to global variables.

---

As a general advice, you should avoid using global data because of the problems it tends to create when the code grows and needs to be maintained. If you intend to expand this code further, you should look into refactoring it to either a more object-oriented or more functional design.

An object-oriented solution would encapsulate the global variables and their management inside classes. One obvious starting point would be moving dfs() inside the Graph class with all the necessary data as its members.

A functional design would pass all the variables as parameters to the functions. A simple change to your code would be to declare the global variables inside the main() function and pass them to dfs() and other functions as needed.